# Does Apple charge for Paypal transactions?

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to integrate Paypal payment gateway in my iOS application but before that I want to know that "does Apple take any fees for the transaction as I am doing it through Paypal and not the In-App Purchase?". I know that Paypal take around 3.50% + $0.15 for each transaction.

Comment: I think they wont, but im not 100% sure, but if there is an SDK for iOS and they let you publish your app in the AppStore I think you just have to pay the Paypal fees

Comment: If you are creating an e-commerce app then I can't see why Apple should ask for a cut of the transaction amount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple takes 30% of any transaction done with their [StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html).
They do not take any percentage of any other payment system.

But most importantly, you can not use any other payment system than Apple's own system for digital goods. So Paypal can only be used for physical goods like Food delivery, clothes, ...

Any digital goods like e-books, music, video, passes for services, etc have to bought via Apple's [StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html).

Comment: Just found this because of the conversations regarding the App "DAMUS". How does it work with a Paypal Friends transaction? There is no need for a physical transaction and I can just send money around. Why is it considered OK with Paypal but Damus is not allowed to have a tip button